# Anyone running for office declared insane so leaders were selected by some other method

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, politics

I seem to recall reading, around 45 to 50 years ago, a science fiction short story or novel where one of the plot mechanisms was that anyone who wanted to run for political office was automatically declared insane, and thus unfit for office.  Thus leaders were to be selected by some other method (Sortition? or by computer?).

The story was not "Franchise" by Asimov, about a randomly chosen voter (I just checked by re-reading it).

Comment: Exactly what part of it is sci-fi or fantasy?

Comment: 2066: Election Day by Michael Shaara?

Comment: @Mooz : Editorial choice? I recall seeing the story possibly in a sci fi collection or magazine.  Perhaps about a futuristic setting...

Comment: Title correction: Could this plot mechanism not have been from a short story, but instead in a novel, such as "Songs of Distant Earth" by Arthur C.Clarke ?

Comment: @hotpaw2 You're the OP, you're able to edit the title if you wish.

Comment: You're sure you're not thinking of The Restaurant at the End of the Universe?  The premise there being that the President wasn't actually in charge of anything, the real ruler being secretly selected by unknown means.  (One of the plot lines revolved around a group of people trying to find out just who *was* actually in charge.)

Comment: Yes, I have the same recollection, and search. It was made into a short Twilight Zone-style TV film as well. It seemed remarkably prescient of the current situation! I thought it was Kurt Vonnegut, but don't seem to be able to find it. It deserves to be found, and recognised for the genius it was/is.

Comment: Hm. Does this ring a bell by chance? That the person most fit for duty was somebody who had absolutely no desire to do it, but once in office did their very best to do the best job that they could in hopes of getting out early for good behavior.

Answer (score 4):

It is paraphrased from Douglas Adams:

> “To summarize: it is a well-known fact that those people who must want
> to rule people are, ipso facto, those least suited to do it.  To
> summarize the summary: anyone who is capable of getting themselves
> made President should on no account be allowed to do the job.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Douglas Adams, The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/4.Douglas_Adams)</sup></sub>

Comment: Additionally, the leaders were a group of people who consulted a rather solipsistic man living alone with a cat.

Comment: This is not it.  In the Hitchhiker's Guide they still had elections for their president.  They elected Zaphod for a start.  It's just that the president only *thought* he had any power.